# How to populate UIPickerView. After creating the outlets in xcode I can NOT seem to find out how to do anything with it

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

So I create and outlet by dragging the UIPicker into the .h file. I'm really new in Xamarin studio, but I have done endless amounts of research and have tried everything. Basically what I want to do is have the picker view give the user an option of numbers and when one is clicked display the amount for that option. I have tried everything I have read online but its somewhat confusing to me. As in where to put the data and what i should type in compared to what is being told. 
I have a app with 2 view controllers the picker view is in the FirstViewController, I assume i put the code in there basically this is what I have but I get errors right from the start saying public PickerModelDelegate(FirstViewController) <___Parser Error: Unexpected symbol 'public' This is my demo I took out of the book just to understand what is going on :/

```
     using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace PickerViewApp
{



    public class PickerModelDelegate : UIPickerViewModel

    public PickerModelDelegate (FristViewController Controller)
    {
        thi
         s.parentController = controller;
        this.transportList = new List<string>()
        {
            "On Foot", "Bivycle", "Motocycle", "Car", "Bus"
        };
        this.distanceList = new List<string>()
        {
            "0.5", "1", "5", "10", "100"
        };
        this.unitList = new List<string>()
        {
            "mi", "km"
        };
        this.transportSelected = this.transportList[0];
        this.distanceSelected = this.distanceList[0];
        this.unitSelected = this.unitList[0];

        int GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
        int GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, int component)
        string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
        void Selected(UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
    }

    private FirstViewController parentController;
    private List<string> transportList;
    private List<string> distanceList;
    private List<string> unitList;
    string transportSelected;
    string distanceSelected;
    string unitSelected;


}
    public partial class FirstViewController : UIViewController
    {



        public FirstViewController () : base ("FirstViewController", null)
        {
            Title = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("First", "First");
            TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("first");







        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm really new at this. Please dont be rude I really want to learn how to do this.
Thanks ahead for any help. I truly do appreciate it!!

Comment: Do I need to add anything the the FristViewController.m file? I outleted in the .h file but I read somewhere I might need to add the array to the .m ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented any of the methods that provide the picker with information on the data source.

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace PickerViewApp
{
    public class PickerModelDelegate : UIPickerViewModel
    {

        List<string> Data;
        public PickerModelDelegate (List<string> data)
        {
            Data = data;

            this.parentController = controller;

            this.transportSelected = this.transportList[0];
            this.distanceSelected = this.distanceList[0];
            this.unitSelected = this.unitList[0];
         }

        public override int GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
        {
            // RETURN THE NUMBER OF COMPONENTS THE PICKER WILL NEED (THE NUMBER OF "SECTIONS" = THE NUMBER OF LISTS OF DATA YOU HAVE)
            return 1;
        }

        public override int GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, int component)
        {
            return Data.Count;
        }

        public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
        {
            return Data[row];
        }
    }

    private FirstViewController parentController;
    private List<string> transportList;
    private List<string> distanceList;
    private List<string> unitList;
    string transportSelected;
    string distanceSelected;
    string unitSelected;

    public partial class FirstViewController : UIViewController
    {

        public FirstViewController () : base ("FirstViewController", null)
        {
            Title = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("First", "First");
            TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("first");

            this.transportList = new List<string>()
            {
                "On Foot", "Bivycle", "Motocycle", "Car", "Bus"
            };

        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            this.Picker.Model = new PickerModelDelegate (transportList);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the "component" parameter in the methods to determine which list you want to get the data for, for that specific component.

Hope that helps!